# Using Paypal on iOS by taking smart card information

Tags: iphone, ipad, payment-gateway, paypal

I am using Paypal for the payment in my iPhone application.I gone through the sample code and I noticed that all the codes in objective c were showing express payment i.e. log in and make the payment.
I understood that but I want the same thing to be done by second method i.e. if the user is not having the account with paypal then he should be able to do the payment by providing his smart card information like its shown here(Direct Payment).
http://vikku.info/programming/payment-gateway/paypal-direct-payment-integration-NVP-made-easy.htm.
But I want it to do it in iPhone and not in PHP.
Any suggestions are most welcome :)

**Update:** As per the link https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECOnMobileDevices ,its possible to pay using PayPal by giving card information.Has anyone tried it?Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using new library libPayPalEC solved my issue as it provides facility to the user to pay using his card